# Yii: Find in Active Record by a PHP Expression

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

Say you have an Active Record model which contains a set of records:

```
id | name
---------
1 | Record1
2 | Record2
3 | Record3
```

Users who has the permission to see each records are stored in another table, using a foreign key to represent the record, in a comma separated way:

```
foreignId | users
-----------------
1         | joe, doe, zoe
2         | joe
3         | doe, zoe
```

There is an authentication manager bizRule which checks if current user has the permission to see a record. You give it the record id and it checks the permissions table to see if the user is in the comma separeted field.

```
Yii::app()->authManager->checkAccess('seeRecord', $id);
```

Is there an easy way using CActiveRecord to pass a PHP Expression "query"? Something like:

```
Record::model()->findByPHPExpression('Yii::app()->authManager->checkAccess('seeRecord', array('id' => 'id'));
```

If the expression returns true for the current record, that record would be added.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some serious non-yii related issue, your database schema is wrong, please read some about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

You should have an intermediate table, if a user can see various records, and a record can be seen by various users, then you need an intermediate table.

Users, Users_cansee_Records, Records

The intremediate table will have 2 primary keys, that are the user_id and record_id respectively

for your example this table will have something like:

```
user | record
--------------
1 | joe
1 | doe
1 | zoe
2 | joe
3 | doe
3 | zoe
```

Yii supprots this "Many many" relationships out of the box. but please read about database normalization, its an important topic, database design is a critical step in any project development.

Comment: Yes, I had read something about normalization before, but I had chosen to do that denormalization in this case. I'm not a database expert at all, so I'll follow your piece of advise and normalize here as well. I suppose there has to be strong reasons to denormalize. Thank you, @Asgaroth

Comment: If you create InnoDB tables with MySQL (or any other RDMB with foreign keys) gii will create your relations automatically.
If you're working with MySQL this tool may be useful for you: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Thanks @schmunk, at the moment I'm using phpmyadmin but I'll give a chance to workbench soon